# Save data with relation (Nodejs / loopback 4 / mongoDB)

Tags: node.js, loopback4

I can not post data json with relation object.

I use mongoDB.
I have 3 table: table_1, table_2, table_3.

I create relation `EmbedsMany` and `EmbedsOne`:
- table_2 `EmbedsOne` table_1.
- table_2 `EmbedsMany` table_3.

I don't know create post data json to create a new item of table_2 with item of table_1.

```js
import { ..., embedsMany, embedsOne } from '@loopback/repository';
import { Model1, Mode1WithRelations } from './model-1.model';
import { Model3, Model3WithRelations } from './model-2.model';
@model({
    settings: {
        strictObjectIDCoercion: true,
        mongodb: {
            collection: 'table_2'
        }
    }
})
export class Model2 extends Entity {
    @property({
        type: 'string',
        id: true,
        mongodb: {
            dataType: 'ObjectID' // or perhaps 'objectid'?
        }
    })
    id?: string;

    @embedsMany(() => Model3)
    model3?: Model3[];

    @embedsOne(() => Model1)
    model1: Model1;
}

export interface Model2Relations {
    // describe navigational properties here
    model3?: Model3WithRelations[];
    model1: Mode1WithRelations;
}

export type Model2WithRelations = Model2 & Model2Relations;
```

Repository model 2

```js
import { DefaultCrudRepository } from '@loopback/repository';
import { Model2, Model2Relations } from '../models';
import { DbDataSource } from '../datasources';
import { inject } from '@loopback/core';

export class Model2Repository extends DefaultCrudRepository<
    Model2,
    typeof Model2.prototype.id,
    Model2Relations
    > {
    constructor(
        @inject('datasources.DB') dataSource: DbDataSource,
    ) {
        super(Model2, dataSource);
    }
}
```

Json data post

```
{
  "address": "string",
  "status": 1,
  "createdAt": "2019-08-04T03:57:12.999Z",
  "updatedAt": "2019-08-04T03:57:12.999Z",
  "model1": {
     "id": "5d465b4cd91e484250d1e54b" /* id of exist item in table_1 */
  }
}
```

Controller is generate by `lb4 controller`

Expected:
 - Item is save success into table_2 with `EmbedsOne` item of table_1.

Actual:
 - Error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "statusCode": 422,
        "name": "ValidationError",
        "message": "The `Model2` instance is not valid. Details: `model1` is not defined in the model (value: undefined).",
        "details": {
            "context": "Model2",
            "codes": {
                "project": ["unknown-property"]
            },
            "messages": {
                "model1": ["is not defined in the model"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR
According to the `Loopback 4` team, 
`@embedsOne`
`@embedsMany`
`@referencesOne`
`@referencesMany`
has not implemented yet (2019-Sep-03). (See [docs](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Decorators_repository.html#other-decorators) or [github](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/issues/1450))

But I found these decorators and their classes on the [sourcecode](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-next/blob/1edbc0bfbb07be3fca899286488c2c5196da2d47/packages/repository/src/relations/relation.decorator.ts#L47)
So, hopefully, we have to wait untill the implementation is complete. I'll try to update this answer if I got anything new.